# UI Test bundle identifier and code coverage

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I've copied some UI Tests from another project into the current one I am working on. I used KIF for this. 
When I tried to run the UI Tests, they wouldn't run, won't show code coverage data and will display an error with the wrong app name.

[image: UI test error]

I tried several solutions and none of them worked.

I removed KIF from my project and created a new UI Test target. It didn't work.
I copied the Unit Test target and modified all Pods with UI after the app name. It seemed to work but the record button was gone and it was acting as a Unit Test.

I checked all the Build Setting for the UI Test target and it seems to be fine. It's getting the name from the current app, but when I run the test, it still shows "SimpleNoteTakingApp".

Apart from that, I get the code coverage data generation failed warning. 
How will I be able to run UI tests for the current project?

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the `DerivedData` folder from `User/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` from the command-line using `rm -rf DerivedData`. 
Build the project and everything worked as expected. Now the UI Tests run with no problem.

Comment: This is an intermittent issue that you're like to run into. I've entered in radar bug reports and they've been rejected as duplicates so hopefully it gets fixed soon. It's anecdotal but it's been noticeably less frequent since Xcode 9. Fingers crossed.